# Enzyme can't find setupTests file for React app when using Travis CI

Tags: reactjs, heroku, travis-ci, enzyme

I'm trying to deploy a React app (with express on the backend) on Heroku using Travis for CI. All tests pass locally but I'm having an issue with Enzyme. For each tested component I get this message on Travis:

> FAILsrc/tests/HomePage.test.js
>
> > ●Test suite failed to run
> >
> > > Cannot find module '../../src/setupTests' from 'HomePage.test.js'
> > >       at Resolver.resolveModule (node_modules/react-scripts/node_modules/jest-> resolve/build/index.js:179:17)
> > >       at Object. (src/tests/HomePage.test.js:3:1)

It looks like my path to the setupTests.js file is wrong but how could it work locally?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WZU9M.png)

If I don't import the setupTests file to each component that I test, I get this error message:

> > Enzyme Internal Error: Enzyme expects an adapter to be configured, but >> found none.
> >     To configure an adapter, you should call `Enzyme.configure({ adapter: new Adapter() })`
> >     before using any of Enzyme's top level APIs, where `Adapter` is the 
> >     adapter corresponding to the library currently being tested. For example: import Adapter from 'enzyme-adapter-react-15';

This is how I've configured Travis:

```js
language: node_js
node_js: node
services:
- mongodb
cache:
  directories:
  - node_modules
env:
  - CI=true

script: 
  - cd server && npm install && npm test
  - cd ../client && npm install && npm run build && npm test
deploy:
  provider: heroku
  api_key:
    secure: MY-API-KEY
  app: MY-APP-NAME
  on:
    repo: MY-REPO
```

My setupTests.js

```js
import Enzyme from 'enzyme';
import Adapter from 'enzyme-adapter-react-16';
import { configure } from 'enzyme'

configure({adapter: new Adapter()});
```

My package.json:

```js
{
  "name": "central",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "enzyme-adapter-react-16": "^1.3.1",
    "jwt-decode": "^2.2.0",
    "material-ui": "^0.20.2",
    "moment": "^2.22.2",
    "prop-types": "^15.6.2",
    "react": "^16.4.1",
    "react-dom": "^16.4.1",
    "react-redux": "^5.0.7",
    "react-router-dom": "^4.3.1",
    "react-stripe-checkout": "^2.6.3",
    "redux": "^4.0.0",
    "redux-form": "^7.4.2",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.3.0",
    "socket.io-client": "^2.1.1",
    "validator": "^10.7.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "proxy": "http://localhost:8080",
  "devDependencies": {
    "enzyme": "^3.5.0",
    "mock-local-storage": "^1.0.5",
    "react-scripts": "^1.1.4",
    "react-test-renderer": "^16.4.2"
  }
}
```

What am I doing wrong?
Help much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the issue came from the fact I had client and API on the same repo with various packages.json. I assigned different repos to client and API and I'm not running into that issue anymore.

Comment: That's a real shame. I spent a lot of time merging my (currently combined) repo a few days ago with the express intent of having all of my GitHub issues etc. in one place, and I really didn't want that to be the case. Surely there must be another way.

Comment: There are some developers using that same pattern and it seems to work. There is definitely a way. Separating client from API was just a better option in my case.
Good luck!